# Uploading a large file through HttpWebRequest or HttpClient, does not write the whole content of the file

Tags: file, httpwebrequest, httpclient

I am trying to do a http post  a large files (approx 40 MB to 50MB) to mvc rest api. 
I was able to achieve this using RestSharp restclient, but while using AddFile, it always add starting and trailing text which is unwanted.

I have later tried HttpWebRequest and HttpClient, and both of them fail to write the complete filestream.

I have tried all the examples from this site, but nothing has worked.

```
 HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
        wr.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.KeepAlive = true;

        Stream rs = wr.GetRequestStream();
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(xmlConfigurationFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        fileStream.Close();


        rs.Flush();

        WebResponse wresp = null;
        try
        {
            wresp = wr.GetResponse();
            Stream stream2 = wresp.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (wresp != null)
            {
                wresp.Close();
                wresp = null;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            wr = null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the cause of the issue in your scenario, but in case it helps check my self-answered question in this post to know how to inspect what's happening on the Web API post method: [Web API Post hit before HttpWebRequest has finished streaming a large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152589/web-api-post-hit-before-httpwebrequest-has-finished-streaming-a-large-file/)